# Database connection fails when using db authentication, succeeds using OS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-server, enterprise-geodatabase, sql-server, direct-connect

When i attempt to make a connection to a database on my SQL Server 2014 sever via Database connections in ArcCatalog using with db authentication i get

```
"Connection was attempted with an older version of SQL Server Client...."
```

error message. However this is incorrect as the client is up to date. I download and re-installed the 2014 Client.

Also when i use "OS Authentication" i can connect just fine.

ArcGIS 10.3, ArcGIS for Server 10.3, SQL Server 2014.

The account in question is not a account in our AD (active directory) just and account in the db
resolved.

Comment: http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/37287

Comment: Make sure you have Service Pack 1 installed for your SQL 2012 client.

Comment: @NickO download and install the latest service pack which i guess in now SP2 (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131321(v=sql.120).aspx) but still no dice.

Comment: What version of the native client did you install? I *think* you have to use the 32 bit version of the SQL Server native client for ArcGIS Desktop, even if your workstation is 64 bit. I just use the version of the SQL Server native client that came with the ArcGIS installer. Also make sure your database is set to allow mixed mode authentication. Finally ArcGIS Server requires the 64bit version of the native client. Again use the native client that comes with the software download, it includes both versions of the client.32 and 64 bit.

Comment: @Dowlers 64bit. i will try the 32bit

Comment: Hello, did you solve the problem? I have a similar one. Tried with both the 32 bit and the 64 bit native clients and I get the same error.  "Connection was attempted with an older version of SQL Server client communications software that is not compatible with the SQL Server database server"

Comment: @Ligia yes.  for me i ended up needing the ODBC driver 11 for SQL Server.  It used to be that you needed the SQL Server Native Client but no now its the ODBC driver 11 for SQL  http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36434

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was the ODBC driver 11 for SQL Server that was missing. It seems that the drivers are the SQL Native Client

Comment: consider marking your own answer.

Comment: @FaridCher. Done. i think. Still figuring out how to properly use stackexchange.